# How to get the next and previous image title from attachment or gallery?

Tags: posts, attachments, gallery, php, images

I'm trying to build a slider exactly like [this](http://pigeonsandplanes.com/2012/12/the-15-best-songs-about-the-end-of-the-world/s/blackalicious-sky-is-falling/) in wordpress. I have managed to make the slider work except the next/prev button. I need to get the next image title and the previous image title for the next/prev button. my code is like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

  var clist_autoplay = false;
  var ctemp_autoplay = clist_autoplay;

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
    var larr = { 


<?php  //This is the desired value of Looping

$num=1;foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
    $image_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'large' );



      $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
  $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
$caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
  $description = $attachment->post_content;     
?>
            "<?php echo $image_title ?>": {
            "0": "<?php echo  $image_img[0] ?>",
            "1": 600,
            "2": 400,
            "3": "<?php echo $image_title ?>",
            "4": "#",
            "5": "<?php echo $image_title ?>",
            "6": "",
            "7": "",
            "8": "",
            "9": "",
            "num": <?php  echo $num++; ?>,
            "slideTitle": "<?php echo $caption ?>",
            "slideContent": "<p><?php echo $description; ?></p>",
            "slideNum": null,
            "next": "<?php echo $image_title ?>",
            "prev": "<?php echo $image_title ?>"
        },
        <?php    
     }
}

endwhile;
?>
```

I can't get the `"next": "<?php echo $image_title ?>", "prev": "<?php echo $image_title ?>"` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an associative array of `$attach_id => $attach_obj` and loop through it. While there are methods to get the next and previous elements in this array, I would prefer to rely on continuous index array to get these objects. First convert the array:

```
$images = array_values($images);
```

Now loop through using the contineous index:

```
foreach ($images as $index => $attachment) {
```

Finally check for next and previous objects:

```
<?php if (isset($images[$index+1])) { ?>
    , "next": "<?php echo $images[$index+1]->post_title; ?>"
<?php } ?>
<?php if (isset($images[$index-1])) { ?>
    , "prev": "<?php echo $images[$index-1]->post_title; ?>"
<?php } ?>
```

Edit: here how your code might look like:

```
<script>
    var clist_autoplay = false;
    var ctemp_autoplay = clist_autoplay;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
        var larr = {
<?php
$num = 1;
$images = array_values($images);
foreach ($images as $key => $attachment) {
    $image_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
    $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
    $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
    $description = $attachment->post_content;     
?>
            "<?php echo $image_title ?>": {
                "0": "<?php echo  $image_img[0] ?>",
                "1": 600,
                "2": 400,
                "3": "<?php echo $image_title ?>",
                "4": "#",
                "5": "<?php echo $image_title ?>",
                "6": "",
                "7": "",
                "8": "",
                "9": "",
                "num": <?php  echo $num++; ?>,
                "slideTitle": "<?php echo $caption ?>",
                "slideContent": "<p><?php echo $description; ?></p>",
                "slideNum": null
                <?php if (isset($images[$key+1])) { ?>
                    , "next": "<?php echo $images[$key+1]->post_title; ?>"
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if (isset($images[$key-1])) { ?>
                    , "prev": "<?php echo $images[$key-1]->post_title; ?>"
                <?php } ?>
                }
<?php } // end foreach ?>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm running into problems. http://goo.gl/OsMxe see the source here. the next prev button seemes to be coming like this:
 `"next": "Busta",
 "next": "Morrissey",
 "prev": "Blacka",
  "next": "robbie",
  "prev": "Busta",
  "prev": "Morrissey"`

Comment: here's the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Snowbell92/9dBKs/

Comment: @Snowbell92: 1. You need to numerically index the array `$images = array_values($images)`, 2. You need to loop through the newly created array (replace the old one). Please see my updates for how that implemented on your code.